# Cross-platform Ruby Method to Clear the Terminal Screen

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, macos

How do I make sure that my command-line program in Ruby will clear the screen regardless of whether it is on Windows, MacOSX or a Linux-based distribution?

If I'm on Windows, the command is this:

```
system('cls')
```

Whereas on Linux on Mac it will be this:

```
system('clear')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def clear_screen
  puts "Going to clear the screen"
  if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32|win64|\.NET|windows|cygwin|mingw32/i
    system('cls')
  else
    system('clear')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth keeping in mind that clearing the screen in a program might be your desired behaviour, but it's something that can be irritating if not downright infuriating for people used to a more UNIX-style environment: Killing their scroll-back history is really rude.

The more Ruby and POSIX way of handling this is via [Curses](https://github.com/ruby/curses) ([Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html)), a cross-platform library that gives you a lot of control over how to use the screen to print things, great for building terminal-style interactive applications.

You end up with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
gem 'curses'
require 'curses'

Curses.init_screen

begin
  Curses.crmode

  # Do your calculations here, and to print:
  Curses.addstr("(program output)\n")

  Curses.addstr("Press any key to continue...")

  Curses.refresh

  Curses.getch

ensure
  Curses.close_screen
end
```

Curses is a lot more than a "clear screen" tool, you can add in scrolling, multiple windows, all sorts of things, and when you quit the program it restores your terminal to exactly the same state as before if `close_screen` is called. That's why it's in an `ensure` block, to avoid screwing things up if your program crashes.

Comment: On which system does `clear` kill the scroll-back history?

Comment: Depends on your terminal settings. On some it just forces in a whole page worth of blank lines. In any case, calling `clear` is just plain rude. If I wanted my screen cleared, I'd press the shortcut that clears it, like `CTRL+L`.